# Converting HTML with CSS to word document

Tags: pandoc

I am trying to convert my html file that has css file to word document, but it doesn't seem to convert. it just outputs the css in text at the top of the document

I have the following files:

```
report.html
report.css
```

I am trying to run the following cli command to generate the word document.

```
pandoc -s -css css/report.css report.html -o report.docx
```

Answer (score 1):

From the [pandoc MANUAL](http://pandoc.org/MANUAL.html):

> Pandoc attempts to preserve the structural elements of a document, but not formatting details such as margin size. And some document elements, such as complex tables, may not fit into pandoc’s simple document model. While conversions from pandoc’s Markdown to all formats aspire to be perfect, conversions from formats more expressive than pandoc’s Markdown can be expected to be lossy.

The `--css` option is only useful for HTML-based output formats. For layouting/styling docx output, see [the `--reference-doc` option](http://pandoc.org/MANUAL.html#option--reference-doc).